# telnet source IP

Tags: windows-server-2003, telnet

I have a multihomed Windows 2003 server. Is there a way to specify the source IP address to use with the telnet client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a static route to the host you are connecting to.

For example...

You connect to 10.10.6.5

Interface 1: 192.168.1.50/32
 
Interface 2: 192.168.2.50/32
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
Static route for 192.168.2.0/24 to 192.168.2.1

If you want to connect to 10.10.6.5 via 192.168.2.1, you add this static route:

`route add 10.10.6.5 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.52`

Answer (score 3):

on linux, it's

```
telnet -b source-ip dest-ip
```

to "bind" to a different interface

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/):

```
ncat -s 10.0.50.3 -t 10.1.1.1
```